# How to deal a card using F#

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I've been working on modeling a popular card game (Love Letter) using F# to learn more about functional programming.

```
module Game = 
open Cards
open Players

type Deck = Card list

let dealACard (deck:Deck) = 
    let randomGenerator = System.Random()
    let index = randomGenerator.Next deck.Length
    let card = deck.Item index
    (card, (deck |> List.filter((<>) card)))

let createPlayer playerNumber deck =
    let card, newDeck = dealACard deck
    ({cards=[card]; playerNumber=playerNumber}, newDeck)
```

I've been doing well until I got to how to model how to draw a card. To test this, I wanted to draw all the cards from the deck. My program would look something like this:

```
let deck = createDeck
while not deck.IsEmpty do
    let card, newDeck = dealACard deck
    // print the card
    // how do I update the deck?
```

Any help or feedback would be great.

Comment: In a functional programming style, you can replace your loop by a tail recursive function using pattern matching and you can update your deck using the fact that a list is an immutable data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could shuffle the deck with a `List.sortBy` and then perform a head tail pattern match in the `dealACard` method to return an `Option` of the top card and the new deck or `None` if there are no more cards in the deck.

```
type DealResult = {
    Card : Card
    Deck : Deck
}

let shuffle deck = 
    let random = new System.Random()
    deck |> List.sortBy (fun x -> random.Next())

let dealACard deck =
    match deck with
    | [] -> None
    | card::restOfDeck -> Some { Card = card; Deck = restOfDeck }
```

You could also make `shuffle` a higher order function by allowing a random number generating function to be applied

```
let shuffle random deck =
    deck |> List.sortBy (fun x -> random())
```

Example Usage

```
let deck = [{Rank = 1}; {Rank = 2}] |> shuffle
//val deck : Card list = [{Rank = 2;}; {Rank = 1;}]

let draw1 = deck |> dealACard
//val draw1 : DealResult option = Some {Card = {Rank = 2;}; 
//                                      Deck = [{Rank = 1;}];}

let draw2 = match draw1 with 
            | Some d -> d.Deck |> dealACard
            | None -> None
//val draw2 : DealResult option = Some {Card = {Rank = 1;};
//                                Deck = [];}


let draw3 = match draw2 with 
            | Some d -> d.Deck |> dealACard
            | None -> None
//val draw3 : DealResult option = None
```

#### Addition per Comments

To keep track of the current state of the deck in an immutable way you would probably have some sort of recursive function that accepts a deck

```
type DealResult = {
    Card : Card option
    Deck : Deck
}

let dealACard deck =
    match deck with
    | [] -> { Card = None; Deck = deck }
    | card::restOfDeck -> { Card = Some card; Deck = restOfDeck }

let rec dealAllCards deck =
    let result = deck |> dealACard
    match result.Card with 
    | None -> printfn "Cards out"
    | Some c -> 
        printfn "%A" c
        result.Deck |> dealAllCards

let deck = [(Two, Hearts); (Three, Hearts); (Four, Hearts)] |> shuffle

dealAllCards deck
//(Three, Hearts)
//(Four, Hearts)
//(Two, Hearts)
//Cards out
```

Comment: `Option.map` would be a little nicer than those match expressions, though. ;-)

Comment: This solution is a much closer to the problem I'm trying to solve and I like the idea of using Option. With that being said, how in the world would I maintain the state of the deck without having to declare multiple variables?

Comment: edited the response to include an example of a recursive function to handle the fact that the deck "changes".

Comment: You're answwr included the recursive solution that I hadn't thought of before, thanks for the help, Reid

Comment: The shuffle function is extremely flawed, as explained here (see Sorting section) : en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 6):

An F# list is **immutable**, so if `deck.IsEmpty` starts out `false`, it'll stay `false` forever. There's really no reason to make things so complicated, though.

Assume that you have a sorted deck. Let's use only three cards as an example, but assume that it's a full deck:

```
let deck =
    [
        { Suit = Hearts; Face = Queen }
        { Suit = Diamonds; Face = King }
        { Suit = Spades; Face = Ace }
    ]
```

You can easily scramble the deck using a random number generator:

```
let r = Random ()
let scrambledDeck = deck |> List.sortBy (fun _ -> r.Next ())
```

The first time you create `scrambledDeck`, it may look like this in FSI:

```
> let scrambledDeck = deck |> List.sortBy (fun _ -> r.Next ());;

val scrambledDeck : Card list =
  [{Suit = Spades;
    Face = Ace;}; {Suit = Hearts;
                   Face = Queen;}; {Suit = Diamonds;
                                    Face = King;}]
```

But if you do it again, it might look like this:

```
> let scrambledDeck = deck |> List.sortBy (fun _ -> r.Next ());;

val scrambledDeck : Card list =
  [{Suit = Spades;
    Face = Ace;}; {Suit = Diamonds;
                   Face = King;}; {Suit = Hearts;
                                   Face = Queen;}]
```

Now you have a scrambled deck, and you can simply start pulling cards off it, for example in order to print them:

```
scrambledDeck |> List.iter (printfn "%O")
```

Comment: For an exercise this will be fine. If you care about the quality of the shuffle, consider the Fisher-Yates shuffle. If you use the version here http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#F.23 and define your stock deck as an array, you could do `let scrambledDeck = deckArray |> FisherYatesShuffle |> Seq.toList`

Comment: Fair enough; System.Random may not be random enough. I'm no cryptography expert, but IIRC a [RandomNumberGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx) should also give you a decent shuffle.

Comment: That's a really good point about the while loop always being true/false depending on the contents, I hadn't thought about that. This is a good way to print out the card, but I need to somehow figure out a way to actually have the deck shrink so that the next time a card is drawn, it can't draw a duplicate.

Comment: @CameronPresley If you want to do it the *Functional* way, you can't shrink (mutate) a deck. Instead, if you want the shrinked deck, you can use the solution outlined by Reid Evans where the function returns the drawn card, as well as the shrinked deck.

Comment: @MarkSeemann, if I follow Reid's suggestion, how would I keep track of the deck? I really don't want to mutate it because that violates the spirit of functional programming.

Comment: In Reid's suggestion, you get the remaining deck as the `Deck` element of the `DealResult` return value.

Comment: You must have something else in mind when you write *keep track of the deck*, but I don't think I can guess what it is.

Comment: @Mark, you missed the point, the shufflling function is extremely flawed, for other reasons than you seem to think, as explained here (see Sorting section) : en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle