# How to Model Drawing Cards in F#

Tags: f#

I'm working on modeling how to draw a playing card from the deck and I came up with the following solution:

```
type Card = { Value:int }
type Deck = Card list
type Player = { Hand : Card list }

type CardDrawer(deck) =
     let mutable deck = deck
     member this.drawCard () =
          match deck with
          | h::t ->
               deck <- t
               h
     member this.getDeck () = deck

//Example Usage
let createPlayers deck numPlayers =
     let cardDrawer = new CardDrawer(deck)
     let drawCard = cardDrawer.drawCard
     let createPlayer drawCard =
         let hand = [drawCard(); drawCard()]
         {Hand=hand}

     ([1 .. numPlayers] |> List.map(fun _ -> createPlayer drawCard)),cardDrawer.getDeck()
```

The main problem with this solution is that I'm using a mutable field for the CardDrawer to get the modified deck back. I feel like using a computational expression would work here, but I'm not sure on how to implement it.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

EDIT:
Here's an alternative setup, but how would I have createPlayer know how to take the mutated output and turn it back into input?

```
// Create a function that draws a card
let drawCard deck ()= 
     match deck with
     | h::t -> (h,t)

// Function given a deck and number of players, will return all the players and the deck
let createPlayers deck numPlayers =

     // Function given a deck, will return the player and the new deck
    let createPlayer deck =
        let card, deck = drawCard deck ()
        let card', deck = drawCard deck ()
        { Hand = [card; card'] }, deck

     // But what would this look like now? 
     // How can I get the deck coming back from createPlayer 
     // used for the input to the next time createPlayer is called?
     ([1 .. numPlayers] |> List.map(fun _ -> createPlayer deck)
```

Comment: IMO `CardDrawer` is just a bad abstraction to begin with. You probably want a generator or a sequence.

Comment: You already asked a similar question last year: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31709509/126014 How is this question different?

Comment: @MarkSeemann - I did ask this question last year, but the context is different. Last year, I was trying to find a way to return the elements, this year, I'm trying to figure out a way to change the deck and still use List.map to turn an array of numbers into a Player.

Comment: @CameronPresley The answer is still the same: you don't *change* the deck; you return a new deck, which is the previous deck with the drawn card removed.

Comment: @MarkSeemann - I hear you on that and I understand that my question wasn't clear enough. I've updated the description to be more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it as a **fold**:

```
// Function given a deck and number of players, will return all the players and the deck
let createPlayers deck numPlayers =

    // Function given a deck, will return the player and the new deck
    let createPlayer deck =
        let card, deck = drawCard deck ()
        let card', deck = drawCard deck ()
        { Hand = [card; card'] }, deck

    let dealToNewPlayer (players, deck) _ =
        let player, deck = createPlayer deck
        player :: players, deck

    [1..numPlayers] |> List.fold dealToNewPlayer ([], deck)
```

`List.fold` has the type `('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> 'T list -> 'State`. In this case, because we kick off the fold with `[1..numPlayers]`, which has the type `int list`, the generic type argument `'T` is `int`. Therefore, you need to define a `folder` function with the type `'State -> 'int -> 'State`.

Each time this function is called, you want to accumulate the state, which means that you want to use the previous value of `deck` to calculate the new value of `deck`. You also want to take the generated `Player` and add to a list of already generated `Player` values. This means that the state you need to keep track of must contain *both* a list of `Player` values, and the deck. The simplest way to keep track of both is via a tuple - for example `Player list * Card list`. This means that your `folder` function must have the type `Player list * Card list -> int -> Player list * Card list`.

The above `dealToNewPlayer` function has the type `Player list * Card list -> 'a -> Player list * Card list`, because it ignores the second argument. Because it's generic, it also fits the type `Player list * Card list -> int -> Player list * Card list`.

The other argument to `List.fold` you need is the initial state: `([], deck)`. This value is a tuple where the first element is an empty list of `Player` values, and the second element is the full deck. It fits the state type of `Player list * Card list`.

The return value of this particular `List.fold` is the accumulated state, that is `Player list * Card list`. Thus, the entire type of `createPlayers` is `Card list -> int -> Player list * Card list`.

Here's an example of an FSI session that uses this function:

```
> let deck = List.init 10 (fun i -> { Value = i });;

val deck : Card list =
  [{Value = 0;}; {Value = 1;}; {Value = 2;}; {Value = 3;}; {Value = 4;};
   {Value = 5;}; {Value = 6;}; {Value = 7;}; {Value = 8;}; {Value = 9;}]

> createPlayers deck 3;;
val it : Player list * Card list =
  ([{Hand = [{Value = 4;}; {Value = 5;}];};
    {Hand = [{Value = 2;}; {Value = 3;}];};
    {Hand = [{Value = 0;}; {Value = 1;}];}],
   [{Value = 6;}; {Value = 7;}; {Value = 8;}; {Value = 9;}])
```

As you can see, it deals from the input `deck` to 3 players, so the first element returned is a list of `Player` values, with the cards dealt to each player. The second element of the tuple contains the remaining deck.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it really helped me understand your thought process on the problem.